# After creating a React Project with npx create-react-app, the project doesn't compile

Tags: reactjs

I ran the command `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript` and when I tried to start the project with `npm start`, I got the following errors.

```
Starting the development server...

One of your dependencies, babel-preset-react-app, is importing the
Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './App' in 'PATH\reddit-react\src'
ERROR in ./src/index.tsx 7:0-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './App' in 'PATH\reddit-react\src'

ERROR in ./src/index.tsx 8:0-48
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './reportWebVitals' in 'PATH\reddit-react\src'

ERROR in [eslint] Failed to load parser '@typescript-eslint/parser' declared in 'package.json » eslint-config-react-app#overrides[0]': Cannot find module 'typescript'
Require stack:
- PATH\reddit-react\node_modules\@typescript-eslint\typescript-estree\dist\convert.js
- PATH\reddit-react\node_modules\@typescript-eslint\typescript-estree\dist\ast-converter.js
- PATH\reddit-react\node_modules\@typescript-eslint\typescript-estree\dist\parser.js
- PATH\reddit-react\node_modules\@typescript-eslint\typescript-estree\dist\index.js
- PATH\reddit-react\node_modules\@typescript-eslint\parser\dist\parser.js
- PATH\reddit-react\node_modules\@typescript-eslint\parser\dist\index.js
- PATH\reddit-react\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\dist\eslintrc.cjs

webpack compiled with 3 errors
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Just to be on the safe side: You did run `npm install`?

Comment: I just run it and I still have these errors.

Comment: You’ve done absolutely nothing else with the generated project? What versions of everything (node, cra, at least)? Asking because it works fine for me.

Comment: I managed to get it working, when I was creating the react app the react-app-env.d.ts file was missing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was creating the React App the file react-app-env.d.ts was missing and I had a lot of issues. After installing and trying different versions of Node with nvm I managed to get it working with the latest lts version.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue yesterday I just updated the node version to v20 ( I was using node v14 you can run `node -v` to see what version you are using ) then ran npm install after deleting `package.lock` and `node_modules` and all things worked with me.